# None of the following candidate is applicable because of receiver type mismatch in `HashMap.getOrDefault()` function

Tags: dictionary, kotlin, hashmap

According to the official Oracle documentation, the `HashMap.getOrDefault(Object Key, V defaultValue)` function can take two arguments, but the compiler reported an error when I run the following program.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val numbersMap = mapOf(
        "one" to 1, 
        "two" to 2, 
        "three" to 3,
        "four" to 4,
        "five" to 5
    )
    println(numbersMap.get("one"))
    println(numbersMap["one"])
    println(numbersMap.getOrDefault("four", 10))
    println(numbersMap["five"])
}
```

---

```
C:\Users\forestfh\Documents\KotlinProjects>kotlinc GetOrDefault.kt
GetOrDefault.kt:11:24: error: unresolved reference. None of the following candid
ates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun <R, T : String> Result<String>.getOrDefault(defaultValue: Stri
ng): String defined in kotlin
    println(numbersMap.getOrDefault("four", 10))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`getOrElse()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-else.html) extension function to retrieve either a stored value or default value:

```
println(numbersMap.getOrElse("four") { 10 })
```